Roesser model for 2D FIR filter
I would like to optimize a 2D filter with an $H_\infty$ constraint. For this I would like to use the generalized Kalman-Yakubovich-Popov (KYP) lemma in order to translate the constraint into a linear matrix inequality (LMI).
I found a paper that exactly does this : "https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4684853"
It describes the FIR filter in a state space representation using the Roesser model and then converts the frequency domain $H_\infty$ inequality constraint into an LMI.
To achieve this, the authors write the FIR filter in "canonical" state space representation of the Roesser model, as follows :
$$
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
x^h[i+1, j] \\
x^v[i, j+1]
\end{bmatrix} &= 
A \begin{bmatrix}
x^h[i, j] \\
x^v[i, j]
\end{bmatrix}
+ Bu[i, j] \\
y[i, j] &=
C
\begin{bmatrix}
x^h[i, j]
x^v[i, j]
\end{bmatrix}
+ Du[i, j]
\end{split}
$$
Their "canonical" state space realization of the FIR filter supposedly only has the coefficients contained in the matrices C and D. This way, matrices A and B are considere as constants and the inequalities given in the paper are actually LMIs.
For the canonical representation of the 2D Roesser model, the authors refer to "T. Kaczorek, Two-dimensional Linear Systems. Springer Verlag 1985" (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0005617). This reference indeed describes a canonical realization in chapter 2 section 6.3. However, it seems that the canonical representation of A and B would depend on the FIR coefficients and therefore would break the linearity of the matrix inequalities.
My question is therefore, given a 2D FIR filter with input-output response
$$
y[n_1, n_2] = \sum_{i=0}^{N_1-1}\sum_{j=0}^{N_2 - 1}g[k_1, k_2]u[n_1, - k_1, n_2 - k_2],
$$
where $y$ is the output and $u$ the input, $g[k_1, k_2]$ are the filter coefficients,
how can I have a Roesser 2D state space representation of a FIR filter in which the matrices A and B have a fixed structure and the filter coefficients are only contained inside the matrices C and D ?
Thank you very much !
